# Add click gesture recognizer on stack child (item in scroll)

Tags: c#, xamarin

I've got a stack layout inside a gridview, that I use as a sort of list.
The "items" in the list have to be click/tap -able, but I can't find a way to make the child area clickable while also giving a value to the event to know what item the user clicked.

Right now I create 20 items in a for loop. The "i" is an integer used for counting.
I put an BoxView over the original boxview and label of the item, which is transparent and gets the gesturerecognizer.

```
var clickableBoxv = new BoxView
{
    BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
    Margin = new Thickness(0, 5, 0, 5)
};

clickableBoxv.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
{
    Command = new Command(() => Item_Clicked(i)),
});

private void Item_Clicked(int num)
{
    DisplayAlert("Alert", num.ToString(), "OK");
}
```

But when I click the item, it shows an alert with only the last added number. (which didn't surprise me). But how can I get the alert to show me the specific item number?

Comment: Try setting the background colour of your last BoxView and you will likely see that it is filling all of the available space.

Comment: Try that without the transparent on the BoxView. Maybe because the BoxView is transparent it isn't accepting the click event.

Comment: @Bijington It perfectly fills the right spaces

Comment: @micaelcunha It does respond to the event, only it only gives the last added value to the handler, which is logical, but I dont't want that to happen. But I don't know how to give it the specific value of the specific item.

Comment: Out of interest why aren't you using a `ListView`?

Comment: @Bijington Because I can't style that the way it has to be.

Comment: What you will likely need to do is store the `int` value elsewhere, either in a separate list and have a method of finding it. If you have a list of `BoxView`s then the index within that list could be used. Failing that consider putting some data within the `BindingContext`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I haven't tested your exact code I have reproduced the same behaviour with some Actions inside a for loop.

**Option 1 - Track the boxes.**

It might not be the most ideal of solutions but one option would be to keep track of your boxes and use their index in the collection to represent the number.

```
// 1. A place to store the boxes.
IList<BoxView> boxes = new List<BoxView>();

var clickableBoxv = new BoxView
{
    BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
    Margin = new Thickness(0, 5, 0, 5)
};

// 2. Keep track of your clickable boxes.
boxes.Add(clickableBoxv);

clickableBoxv.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
{
    // 3. Pass in the box rather than the int.
    Command = new Command(() => Item_Clicked(clickableBoxv)),
});

private void Item_Clicked(BoxView box)
{
    // 4. Use the index as the number.
    DisplayAlert("Alert", boxes.IndexOf(box).ToString(), "OK");
}
```

**Option 2 - sub class BoxView**

```
// 1. Sub class
public class MyBoxView : BoxView
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
}

// 2. Use new sub class
var clickableBoxv = new MyBoxView
{
    BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
    Margin = new Thickness(0, 5, 0, 5),
    Index = i,
};

clickableBoxv.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
{
    // 3. Pass in the box rather than the int.
    Command = new Command(() => Item_Clicked(clickableBoxv)),
});

private void Item_Clicked(MyBoxView box)
{
    // 4. Use the index as the number.
    DisplayAlert("Alert", box.Index.ToString(), "OK");
}
```

Comment: I tried the Second option, and becasue I already had a custom BoxView (Not shown in the code in the Question), I added the Index part to it.  First I got a 0 back, but I added the "i" (the counter used for the for loop) to the index in `var clickable = new MyBoxView`, and now it does exactly what I want. Thanks! (: I couldn't find the solution anywhere and couldn't figure it out myself either (also tried bindingcontent after your comment). Again, thanks a bunch!!

Comment: Excellent news! I have updated my example to include the missing Index assignment